# How to use a base.html for default Wagtail Page instance?

Tags: django, wagtail

Wagtail starts new projects with a single welcome template. However, this template does not inherit from any parent template, such as a `base.html`. In our project, we have previously defined a `base.html` containing global HTML tags and CSS/JavaScript includes.

How can we tell the default Wagtail Page model to display in a template that extends `base.html`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clarify, there are two possible setups, depending on how you create your project:

- If you start a new project from scratch with `wagtail start myproject`, the initial migrations (which exist partly within Wagtail itself, and partly within the project template) will set you up with a `HomePage` model and an initial homepage. The template for this page type lives at `home/templates/home_page.html`, and is already set up to inherit from a base template (which lives at `myproject/templates/base.html`).
- If you follow the documentation for [integrating Wagtail into an existing Django project](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html), the initial migrations (which in this case are entirely within Wagtail) will give you an initial page of type `wagtailcore.Page`. You're not really expected to use this page type directly (not least because it has no fields beyond the title, and no way of adding new ones) - it's only done this way because there are no "proper" page models set up yet, and there needs to be *something* as the initial state of the page tree. The idea is that once you've set up at least one page model within your app, you can create your real homepage, point the Site record at it (in Settings -> Sites), and delete the initial stub one.

Nevertheless, if you really want to give `wagtailcore.Page` a full-fledged template with a base template, you could create a template file inside one of your project's apps at the path `templates/wagtailcore/page.html`. As long as the app in question is *above* `'wagtail.core'` in the INSTALLED_APPS list, this will override the barebones template supplied by Wagtail.

Comment: Not sure how I got into this state, but my index model (inheriting Page) got `content_type` value (in `wagtailcore_page` table) set to 30, which was row `30,wagtailcore,page` in table `django_content_type`. That lead to `wagtailcore/page.html` template being used. I created it again, and then it got the correct `content_type` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Add that to your template, it will extend anything in the base.

If your base template has blocks in it, you use the same syntax

```
{% block content %}
This will appear wherever you have this same block in the base.html template
{% endblock %}
```

Wagtail is built on top of Django, you can read more about its templating language here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/

Comment: Is there a way to do this for the *default* Wagtail Page template? We ended up creating a HomePage model, as described in the documentation.